# Exporting Google Sheet to Open XML Document and writing to disk with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I'm using GSuite's Sheets for some spreadsheets which we use to populate our service's database. I'm writing a small Python script which will backup our files by writing them to a local disk.

A GSuite Sheet object has an `id` and in order to export a Google Sheet, at least according to the documentation, one has to use the `export_media(fileId, mimeType)`

The `mimeType` to which I am exporting is an open office document. Google's example on how to do this is here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#python

My issue is that my files are completely empty. You'll notice some print statements in my code below where an empty bytes string is output.

The request object in my method looks good in the debugger and I don't get any exceptions and the program runs to the end. The downloader reports that it completes the job and has a size of `21033`. I assume that is in bytes.

Here is the loop and the method I am using to export the file and write it to disk.

```py
    service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=delegated_credentials, cache_discovery=False)
    files = service.files().list(**request_data).execute().get("files", [])

    open_type = 'application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet'
    
    for f in files:
        export_file_to_open_office(f, service, open_type)


def export_file_to_open_office(file, drive_service, mime_type):
    request = drive_service.files().export_media(fileId=file["id"], mimeType=mime_type).get()

    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    print(fh.read())  # this outputs b''
    
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print(fh.read())  # this outputs b''
        print("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
    
    with open("my_file.xls", 'wb') as fil:
        fil.write(fh.read())
```

All I really want to do is get my sheet and write it to my disk. Any tips would be very much appreciated.

Cheers,

C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
with open("my_file.xls", 'wb') as fil:
    fil.write(fh.read())
```

#### To:

```
with open("my_file.xls", 'wb') as fil:
    fh.seek(0)  # <--- Added
    fil.write(fh.read())
```

#### Reference:

- [seek()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek)

Comment: Spot on, @Tanaike, thank you!. `seek()`, I'm having flashbacks to my days of C at university.

Comment: @anowlinorbit Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.